# Luis entity is getting triggered on selection of confirmation dialog

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

I have a confirmation dialog in my code-

```
   PromptDialog.Confirm(context, ConfirmDocSearch,
            $"Do you want to search any other document.?", attempts: 1);
```

but when user select yes or no it is getting trigger none dialog on Luis model. I dont want to trigger any Luis intent on Yes or No

Reviewed and retrain luis model.

Comment: Thanks for sharing sample code with your PromptDialog. Could you please share other related parts?